# iPad pro 2021: "you cannot install <x> from your computer. Please visit this link from Safari browser on your iPhone, iPad or iPod."

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, ipados

I'm trying to open a particular link to download an app in Safari on an iPad pro. I keep getting the message:

> "you cannot install  from your computer. Please visit this link
> from Safari browser on your iPhone, iPad or iPod."

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what if you search for the App in the App store?

Comment: Sounds like a developer problem. The web server providing the app may be detecting that the version of Safari on your iPad Pro as not compatible, especially if the app is pretty old and predates the version of Safari. Are you sure the app can run on the version of iOS or iPadOS on this iPad Pro?